# does every bounded region have an area?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find D-bounded subset of $R^2$ such that area(D) = $\int \int _D (1.dA)$ does not exist?

Because rational numbers have a hole in it, I want to use rational number set in an interval to make it bounded. But, i do not know how to give the proof rigorously. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit : Integral is the Riemann integral.

Comment: What is your definition of "area of $D$ exists"?

Comment: the integral(1.dA) on D exist means D has an area

Comment: So you're using the Riemann integral, not the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Just an idea, perhaps you could extend the [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $D=[0,1]\times[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. Then $D$ is not Jordan-measurable, since the characteristic function of $D$ is not Riemann Integrable. Worse yet, there are open bounded sets which are not Jordan-measurable. Let $D=\{P_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be an ordering of $D$ and $C>2$. For each $k\in\mathbb N$, let $A_k$ be an open square centered at $P_k$, contained in $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ of area less than $C^{-k}$. Then $\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ is open, bounded and not Jordan-measurable.

As a consequence of the Lebesgue integrability theorem, a bounded set $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ is Jordan-measurable if and only if its boundary has measure $0$.